# Interpolation function rejected by ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, interpolation, physics

I was playing around with the [bouncing ball example](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/bouncing-balls.html), and decided to make a 3d version.

I decided to use `ParametricPlot3D` for a simple independent 3D presentation.
However, I found that having an interpolating function as the the first element in the list of three functions passed to `ParametricPlot3D` doesn't work.

```
ballz = NDSolve[{z''[t] == -9.81, z[0] == 5, z'[0] == 0,
WhenEvent[z[t] == 0.2, z'[t] -> -0.9 z'[t]]}, z, {t, 0, 10}];

bally = NDSolve[{y''[t] == 0, y[0] == -2, y'[0] == 4, 
WhenEvent[y[t] == 4.8, y'[t] -> -0.9 y'[t]], 
WhenEvent[y[t] == -4.8, y'[t] -> -0.9 y'[t]]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];

Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot3D[{t - 2, y[t] /. bally, z[t] /. ballz}, {t, 0, a}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed, Thick}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {0, 10}}], 
  {a, 0.025, 10, 0.025}]
```

[image]

The above code works fine, but when I substitute by an interpolation function  for the `t - 2` term, the function doesn't work. Can this be fixed?

Comment: While you use the term `Contourplot3D` in your title and text, your code uses `ParametricPlot3D `, which is not the same thing.

Comment: I don't see how we can help you without seeing the code you used to build your interpolating function and the real plot code that failed. Posting code that worked and then giving a vague description about changes you made doesn't cut it.

Comment: Corrected the title.
The interpolating functions are the ones you get from the NDSolve.
So, replacin t-2 with y[t] /. bally doesn't work, but it doesn't work with ANY interpolating function in the first term.

Comment: It works for me in V10.  Exactly what code did not work?

Comment: `y[t] /. bally` is a list. Use `y[t] /. First[bally]` to extract the actual interpolating function.

Comment: @SimonWoods
Thanks, that works, but why do I need to do that in the first term, but not in the second or third term? Nor is it used in the Wolfram example.

Comment: @MichaelE2
I'm using V9, if it works for you, maybe the function has been changed.
Apparently in the first term I need to isolate a term of the IPF, this isn't needed in the other two terms.

Comment: I think it is just an accident that *Mathematica* manages to correctly interpret the unsupported syntax in some cases.

Comment: What works is if I put an `InterpolatingFunction` in for `t-2`, in both V10 and V9.0.1.  I think what you were doing was putting in a **list** containing an `InterpolatingFunction`, such as in one of the examples in the last part of my answer.  That is why I and m_goldberg were asking you to post the exact code that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ParametricPlot3D` and `ParametricPlot` accept a wide range of nested lists of expressions to specify a function or functions to be graphed.  Let's discuss `ParametricPlot3D`. `ParametricPlot` is similar, with lists of length 2 replacing lists of length 3 where appropriate.  There are two types of specifications

```
List[expr,...]
List[List[...],...]
```

where `expr` represents an expression with a head other than `List` and `...` represents expressions possibly nested inside `List`.  Not all inputs will result in a plot, but neither will they result in an error message. My feeling after looking at the plotting examples in the `NDSolve` documentation is that this flexibility was chosen over a having a more rigorous argument checking, for the convenience of visualization.  The output of a simple `NDSolve` such as in the OP's examples is

```
List[List[y -> InterpolatingFunction[...]]]
```

and the result of `y[t] /. bally` is

```
List[InterpolatingFunction[...][t]]
```

so that the `y` coordinate ends up wrapped in a `List`.  I suppose most people learn to use `y[t] /. First[bally]` to avoid the extra `{}`.  However, for plotting, it's not strictly necessary.

For each type of input to `ParametricPlot3D` to produce a plot, it has to satisfy one of the following.

1. In the first case `fn = List[expr,...]` where `expr` is not a `List`, then `Flatten[fn]` should be a `List` of three expressions that are functions of the parameter(s) passed to `ParametricPlot3D`.
2. In the second case, `fns = List[list1, list2,...]`, each of `list1`, etc. should be a `List`; and for `list1` to produce a curve, `Flatten[list1]` should be a `List` of three expressions that are functions of the parameter(s), and so on for the other lists.

Here are a few examples:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t, {t^2}, {t^3}}, {t, 0, 1}]            (* works -- OP's case *)
ParametricPlot3D[{{t}, {t^2}, {t^3}}, {t, 0, 1}]          (* fails criterion 2 -- no curve *)
ParametricPlot3D[{{{t}, {t^2}, {t^3}}}, {t, 0, 1}]        (* works -- note {{...}} *)
ParametricPlot3D[{{{t}, {t^2}, {t^3}}, {t^2, {{{t^3}}}, {t}}}, {t, 0, 1}] (* works *)
```

The OP's example

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t - 2, y[t] /. bally, z[t] /. ballz}, {t, 0, a}]
```

meets the criterion 1, just as does the first example above.  If `ballx` was another solution to a similar `NDSolve`, then

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x[t] /. ballx, y[t] /. bally, z[t] /. ballz}, {t, 0, a}]
```

would be of the form of the second example,

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{x[t]}, {y[t]}, {z[t]}}, {t, 0, a}]
```

which will not produce a plot.  (The input is, probably, interpreted as three 1D parametrizations.)  To fix it, one could wrap the `NDSolve` outputs in `First`: `First[ballx]`, etc. as [@SimonWoods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) mentions in a comment.  Or one could put in extra `{}` as in the third example above:

```
ballx = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == -2}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
ParametricPlot3D[{{x[t] /. ballx, y[t] /. bally, z[t] /. ballz}}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I had tried the IPF of the y-function in the x-function first, (which didn't work) and thought it was a more generalized issue. Guess I should have been more thorough when I didn't get what the issue was.
Regardless, good explanation, I see the issue now, thanks.

Comment: @Feyre What a coincidence, I tried `bally` for x at first, too. :)  Actually, the issue is not explained in the docs, ASAIK.  I didn't really know how extensively forgiving `ParametricPlot` is of extra `{}` until I explored your question -- one usually does the simplest thing after all.  So thanks for that.